# How can I split a url in C# into a Key Value pair?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Url:

https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10154500552625464

that I need to split into a key value pair with:

Value: https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10154500552625464
Key: 10154500552625464

I need to place them in a Dictionary:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> GetVideoLinks(string Data)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex (@"https:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/video.php\?v=?<id>[0-9]{17}");

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Write code that does this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Downvoted for show me the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a framework class for that: [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please read: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)